# Unusual error with code when trying to knit rmd file

Tags: r, knitr

When knitting my rmd file to PDF I keep getting this error even though all my code works fine. Any ideas?

```
Error in transactionData_2 %>% filter(LYLTY_CARD_NBR != 226000):

could not find function "%>%"

Calls: <Anonymous>... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

Comment: Usually `could not find function "%>%"` indicates that you haven't loaded a library with the `"%>%"` ([magrittr pipe](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html#:~:text=The%20magrittr%20pipe%20operators%20use,to%20the%20left%2Dhand%20side.)) function. Do you have e.g. `library(dplyr)` or `library(tidyverse)` at the top of your Rmarkdown file?

Comment: @jared_mamrot just loaded these libraries and it worked. thanks so much!